# How to get date only if time is 00:00:00 from DateTime c#

Tags: c#, date, datetime, cultureinfo

I want to convert  DateTime object to string. What I want to achieve is following things:

1. Get Date only out of it if Time is 00:00:00.
2. Get Date and Time if  both are present.
3. I want to achieve this using `CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat` and
   `Convert.ToString(DateTime, IFormatProvider)`, otherwise I know how
   to do this using `.ToString()` Extension method.

I have tried following things:

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
CultureInfo culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = MPAResource.DateFormat;
culture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "hh:mm:ss tt";
culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern = "hh:mm:ss tt";
culture.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern = MPAResource.DateTimeFormat;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
```

Then:

```
string x = Convert.ToString(x.ExpectedJoiningDate, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Output is `09-Oct-2015 11:00 AM`. I want `09-Oct-2015 11:00 AM` if time is there and `09-Oct-2015` if time is not there.

But above line gives me only date even if time is present with date.

Comment: Why not `if(datetime.time == TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:00")){//then}`?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot create a branching format (do one thing if X, do another thing if not), you must implement this using normal C# code (if-statement).

Comment: Simple, if(myTime != myTime.Date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a while a wrote method for myself.

```
public static string ConvertToMyDateTimeFormat(Nullable<DateTime> value, CultureInfo IFormateProvider)
        {
            if (value.HasValue)
            {
                if (value.Value.TimeOfDay.Ticks > 0)
                {
                    return value.Value.ToString(IFormateProvider);
                }
                else
                {
                    return value.Value.ToString(IFormateProvider.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 9):

Seems to me like this is pretty straight forward:

```
var dt = x.ExpectedJoiningDate;
string x = (dt.TimeOfDay == TimeSpan.Zero)?dt.ToShortDateString():dt.ToString();
```

PS: you can use a culture as parameter in ToString if you like. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326720(v=vs.71).aspx for details on how to do this.

---

Tim made the remark that the OP wants to use `Convert.ToString`. It doesn't compute, so I refuse. Why doesn't it compute? Here's the code for `Convert.ToString`:

```
public static string ToString(DateTime value, IFormatProvider provider)
{
    return value.ToString(provider);
}
```

Yes people, that's basically the same.

That said, if you're stubborn, I guess you can implement `IFormatProvider` in your own little class, change the format provider based on the condition, then pass that instead of the default format provider. Then, congrats, you've created a lot of senseless code that gives the exact same results using `Convert.ToString`.

Comment: Although it's not really an answer since OP needs to use `Convert.ToString` for whatever reasons. But since there is no way to write a conditional format string which you could use for `Convert.ToString` this seems to be the only way.

Comment: I can see symbols I've never used before. :D. No, wait... I've used `:` for division.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Good remark, so +1 for that. I've added an explanation.